# C ascii to hex code

Tags: c, encryption, type-conversion, hex, ascii

I need to convert an ascii input to hex input. I am very bad with C so if you could include some explanation that would be very helpful. This code is just a bunch of bits and pieces but most is probably wrong or useless. Afterwards i need to use user input to select the string but the hard part is getting it to convert at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void crypt(char *buf, char *keybuf, int keylen) {
    //This is meant to encrypt by xor-ing with the sentence and key entered//
    //It is also supposed to replace the original buf with the new version post-xor//
    int i;
    int *xp;
    xp=&i;
    for(i=0; i<keylen; i++) {
    buf[i]=buf[i]^keybuf[i];
    xp++;
    }
}
int convertkey(char *keybuf) {
    int keylen=0;
    //I need to add something that will return the length of the key by incrementing keylen according to *keybuf//
    return keylen;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char x;
    char *xp;
    xp = &x;
    char a[47];
    char *ap;
    ap=a;
    printf("Enter Sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",a);
    printf("Enter key: ");
    scanf("%d",xp);
    printf("You entered the sentence: %s\n",a);
    printf("You entered the key: %d\n",x);

    convertkey(xp);
    crypt(ap,xp,x);
    printf("New Sentence: %s\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not support nested functions, to start with.  Move 'crypt' and 'convertkey' outside of main().

Comment: Sadly, 'most is probably wrong or useless' is a fair appraisal.  I don't think your code can be improved without actually rewriting it from your requirements which, as they are not clear anyway, would be difficult even if someone wanted to do it, which they probably won't.

Comment: "to convert an ASCII input to hex input".  Posing an example or 2 or 3 would help clarify the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final product I was looking for but was very poor at explaining/coding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void crypt(char *buf, char *keybuf, int keylen) {
    int i;
    int length= strlen(buf)-1;
    for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
    buf[i]=buf[i]^keybuf[i%keylen];
    printf("%c",buf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int convertkey(char *keybuf) {
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;keybuf[i]!='\n';i++){
        if(keybuf[i]>='0' & keybuf[i]<='9'){
            keybuf[i]=keybuf[i]-'0';
        }
        else if(keybuf[i]>='a' & keybuf[i]<='f'){
            keybuf[i]=(keybuf[i]-'a')+10;
        }
    }
    return i;
}   

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    char keychars[12];
    char a[48];
    char *ap;
    int i;
    ap=a;
    printf("Enter Sentence: ");
    fgets(a, 48, stdin);
    printf("Enter Key: ");
    fgets(keychars, 12, stdin);
    for (i=0; i<strlen(keychars); i++) {
        char c = keychars[i];
        printf("keychars[%d]=%c (character), %d (decimal), %x (hex)\n", i, c, c, c);
    }
    crypt(ap,keychars,convertkey(keychars));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Such as it is, I have reorganised your posted code so at least it compiles, even if the intent is unclear. Perhaps you can take it on from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// moved out of main()
void crypt(char *buf, char *keybuf, int keylen) { 
    int i;                          // added declaration
    for(i=0; i<keylen; i++) {       // corrected syntax and end condition
        buf[i]=buf[i]^keybuf[i];    
        //xp++;                     // out of scope
    }   
}

// moved out of main()
int convertkey(char *keybuf) {
    int keylen=0;
    return keylen;  
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int x=0;
    int *xp;
    xp = &x;                        // xp=&x{0};
    return 0;                       // exit(0);
}
```